# How to migrate articles from Joomla 1.5 to 3.x?

Tags: joomla-3.x, migration, articles, joomla-1.5

**I am trying to migrate some articles.**

On my host I get 403 errors for J2XML export so I thought I would set it up on a localhost. The front end looks fine unless you try to login. Fortunately I get a list of deprecations and library errors for frontend access but when I try to login administrator side I only get a white screen. No errors, no nothing. I am under the impression this will not be fun so if I simply import articles into 3.x am I going to break it?

Any other suggestions for just moving one 1.5.26 Section of content without copy paste each and every article into 3.2?

Comment: Thanks Valentin. It looks like I need to be concerned about the asset table and SP Upgrade will be probably be mentioned again.

Answer (score 6):

You can try redmigrator(free) or SpUpgrade (commercial).

I try redmigrator four days ago and it works very well, if you only need the articles. If you follow the youtube redmigrator tutorial, it should be easy to migrate your content from J1.5 to J3.3

redmigrator Site: http://redcomponent.com/redcomponent/redmigrator

redmigrator Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=khYZjHtiuZw#

Edit: The good thing with SpUpgrade and redmigrator is, they don't need access to the old site to perform the migrate. They need only access database and files.

Answer (score 6):

I use J2XML which works great and it's free http://www.eshiol.it/joomla/j2xml/j2xml-1503.html

Comment: I was really looking forward to trying this out but I had problems getting the backend of the site to work on my localhost

Answer (score 2):

I use SP upgrade by Cyend. It is a paid extension. But what I consider to be most useful with this extension, is the option to keep the same ids of the migrated data.

Answer (score 0):

So I did a insert into select statement from my old database to new and once I batch moved them the asset table set the keys that were missing.

```
INSERT into newsiteprefix_content (`title`, `alias`, ....) SELECT (`title`, `alias`, ...) FROM oldsite.jos_content WHERE sectionid = ##
```

Thanks. No component clean up and still fairly fresh site. If I could have had my oldsite setup on the newsite same localhost I would have tried all these other options but I think the php versioning may have been causing the problem
I would be interested to know how detrimental the ids are for SEO although I don't think I was ever experiencing awesome SEO to begin with.